# SAP HANA on Ubuntu - xs login results in python error

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04, sap-hana

In installed SAP Hana according to [How to install SAP Hana Express Edition 2.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/07/21/how-to-install-sap-hana-express-edition-2.0-on-ubuntu-18.04-bionic-beaver/comment-page-1/#comment-546557) (issues have been commented in the blog above)

Following this I wanted to explore the XSA environment according to [SAP HANA XS Advanced, explore the basic tools](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/xsa-explore-basics.html)

Unfortunately I ran into a python error:

```
hxeadm@thorsten-VirtualBox:/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90> xs login
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python'
  PYTHONPATH = '/usr/sap/HXE/SYS/global/hdb/custom/python_support:/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/python_support:/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/thorsten-virtualbox:/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe:/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/testscripts:/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python/lib/python2.7'
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/sap/HXE/SYS/global/hdb/custom/python_support',
    '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/python_support',
    '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/thorsten-virtualbox',
    '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe',
    '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/testscripts',
    '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
  File "/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/exe/Python/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00007f8d164ae740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
hxeadm@thorsten-VirtualBox:/usr/sap/HXE/HDB90>
```

Anybody an idea or hint how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Server**

If you want to use `xs login` on the server:

Make sure that you have on the server a directory called xs which contains `bin/xs` usually it is installed in `/hana/shared/HXE/xs/bin/xs`

If this path does not exists your XSA ist not installed correctly.

**Client**

If you want to use `xs login` on the client:

On a client you may install the client tools which come with the xs binary.
Follow this guide : [Installing XS CLI Client](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hxe-ua-install-xs-xli-client.html)

On Linux it looks like this:

[image]